# Is there a good library for Ruby 1.9.2 that processes IRIs ( URLs with special character like ü )

Tags: ruby, url

I'm looking for a library or extension that enables ruby to work with [IRIs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt), which are URLs that contain special characters like Umlauts ( ü,ö and friends ). I'm trying to build a webscraper, and that seems to be the only point that's bothering me.

I've tried some quick hacks to resolve the problem, but I'd feel better if there was a tested and proven library for doing the same thing.

Thanks already for helping me!

moritz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Addressable](http://Addressable.RubyForge.Org/) is a (mostly) API-compatible replacement for the `URI` standard library which supports IRIs among other things.